# Convert minutes into a human readable format

Tags: java, android, date, formatting, android-studio

quick question.

Is there a smarter/sleeker way to convert minutes into a more readable format, showing only the most significant digit?

I'm using Android Studio's Java.

```
public String MinutesToHumanReadable(Long minutes) {

...

}
```

ie

```
2 mins = "2 mins"
45 mins = "45 mins"
60 mins = ">1 hr"
85 mins = ">1 hr"
120 mins = ">2 hrs"
200 mins = ">3 hrs"
1500 mins = ">1 day"
```

My code is very cumbersome, sloppy, and somewhat unreadable.

```
public String MinutesToHumanReadable(long minutes) {
    String sReturn = "";

    if (minutes > 515600) {
        sReturn = "> 1 yr";

    } else if (minutes > 43200) {
        sReturn = (minutes / 43200) + " mths";

    } else if (minutes > 10080) {
        sReturn = (minutes / 10080) + " wks";

    } else if (minutes > 1440) {
        sReturn = (minutes / 1440) + " days";

    } else if (minutes > 60) {
        sReturn = (minutes / 60) + " hrs";

    } else {
        //<60
        sReturn = minutes + " mins";

    }

    return sReturn;
}
```

Many thanks,
J

Comment: For this need, I would just use some `if/else if/else` statements.

Comment: Depending on how much granularity you need, using conditional statements would make most sense.

Comment: Maybe a nice Lib for that: http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/

Comment: There's `android.text.format.DateUtils` with various relative time formatting helpers e.g. `getRelativeTimeSpanString()`. The implementation isn't structurally too different from yours: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/format/DateUtils.java

Comment: Solved it, if you watched answers before, I had a little mistake in the code, so "refresh" it and enjoy :)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I saw you missed "day". I've used your version with a slight change. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is possible, I figure it out and I am proud of it! :)
Note that you can easily add any other value without changing the method itself, only by changing values in these two arrays. For example, if "years" are not enough for you, you can add "decades" and "centuries"...

This code also adding "s" letter at the end, if you have more than 1 of output value.

```
public class SuperMinutesChangerClass {
    public static int[] barriers = {1, 60, 60*24, 60*24*7, 60*24*365, Integer.MAX_VALUE};
    public static String[] text = {"min", "hr", "day", "week", "year"};

    public static String minutesToHumanReadable(int minutes){
        String toReturn = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < barriers.length; i++) {
            if (minutes < barriers[i]){
                int ammount = (minutes/barriers[i-1]);
                toReturn = ">" + (ammount) + " " + text[i-1];
                if (ammount > 1){
                    toReturn += "s";
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }         
}
```

Sample input :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(minutesToHumanReadable(10));
        System.out.println(minutesToHumanReadable(60));
        System.out.println(minutesToHumanReadable(61));
        System.out.println(minutesToHumanReadable(121));
        System.out.println(minutesToHumanReadable(8887));
        System.out.println(minutesToHumanReadable(9999743));
    }
```

Output is :

```
>10 mins
>1 hr
>1 hr
>2 hrs
>6 days
>19 years
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this with a slight change (now you've also changed yours to include 'day')

        int[] minBoundaries =    {1,     60,   60*24, 60*24*7, 60*24*7*4, 60*24*365};
        String[] boundaryNames = {"min", "hr", "day", "wk",    "mth",     "yr"};

Comment: Yea I forgot to add "days" first :)

Answer (score 5):

I would use some dummy `if/else if/else` statements :

```
public static String convert(int minutes) {
  if(minutes < 60) {
    return String.format("%d mins", minutes);
  } else if(minutes % 60 == 0) { // No minutes - i.e. not a fractional hour.
    return String.format("%d hrs", minutes/60);
  } else if(minutes < 1440) { //1 day = 1440 minutes
    return String.format("%d hrs, %d mins", minutes/60, minutes%60);
  } else {
    return String.format("%d days", minutes / 1440);
  }
}
```

#### Sample Output

```
System.out.println(convert(24));   //=> 24 mins
System.out.println(convert(120));  //=> 2 hrs
System.out.println(convert(84));   //=> 1 hrs, 24 mins
System.out.println(convert(2880)); //=> 2 days
```

Comment: This is nice. Clean and simple.

Comment: I modified this with an additional conditional, which is `minutes%60 == 0`, and instead of displaying "0 minutes" it just displays the hours, like "3 hours". Much cleaner for those hourly durations.

Comment: Can you update the answer @JoshuaPinter

Comment: @Sniffer Updated, including better sample output! Happy New Year!

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Thanks man. It's works perfectly,
 Happy New Year too :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps you

```
private static final int MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
private static final int MINUTES_PER_DAY = MINUTES_PER_HOUR * 24;

public String minutesToHumanReadable(long minutes) {
    if (minutes > MINUTES_PER_DAY) {
        return String.format("> %d days", minutes / MINUTES_PER_DAY);
    } else if (minutes > MINUTES_PER_HOUR) {
        return String.format("> %d hours", minutes / MINUTES_PER_HOUR);
    }

    return String.format("%d minutes", minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving answer by Joshua Pinter and Arnaud Denoyelle.

```
    fun convertMinutesToHumanReadable(minutes: Int, context: Context): String {
    return if (minutes < 60) {
        "$minutes ${context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.minutes_abbrev, minutes)}"
    } else if (minutes % 60 == 0 && minutes < 1440) {
        val hours1 = minutes / 60
        "$hours1 ${context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.hours_abbrev, hours1)}"
    } else if (minutes < 1440) {
        val hours1 = minutes / 60
        val minutes1 = minutes % 60
        "$hours1 ${
            context.resources.getQuantityString(
                R.plurals.hours_abbrev, hours1
            )
        }, $minutes1 ${
            context.resources.getQuantityString(
                R.plurals.minutes_abbrev, minutes1
            )
        } "
    } else if (minutes % 1440 == 0) {
        val days1 = minutes / 1440
        "$days1 ${context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.days, days1)}"
    } else {
        val days1 = minutes / 1440
        "$days1 ${context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.days, days1)}, ".plus(
            convertMinutesHumanReadable(minutes % 1440, context)
        )
    }
}
```

And add this to res/values/strings.xml file

```
<plurals name="minutes_abbrev">
        <item quantity="one">min</item>
        <item quantity="other">mins</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="hours_abbrev">
        <item quantity="one">hr</item>
        <item quantity="other">hrs</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="days">
        <item quantity="one">day</item>
        <item quantity="other">days</item>
    </plurals>
```

In this way it will show singular or plural depending on the amount and also supports values ​​larger than one day.  For example: 2 days, 8 hrs, 23 mins or 1 day, 2 hrs, 1 min