# Java Time API - A better way to get total elapsed time

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

This is my first oportunity to play with the "new" java.time package from Java 8.

I need to get the total elapsed time, something like:
`1 day, 2h:3m:4s 5ms`

I know that have 2 `TemporalAmount` implementations for intervals:
 - `Period` for years, months and days
 - `Duration` for hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds and nanoseconds

**There's a way to mix these two or something more straightforward than "do math"?**

That was the best I could do until now:
**(Updated with a new improved version)**

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
// Forcing a long time execution to measure
LocalDateTime end = start
        .plusDays(1)
        .plusHours(2)
        .plusMinutes(3)
        .plusSeconds(4)
        .plusNanos(5000);

LocalDateTime elapsed = end
        .minusDays(start.getDayOfYear())
        .minusHours(start.getHour())
        .minusMinutes(start.getMinute())
        .minusSeconds(start.getSecond())
        .minusNanos(start.getNano());

Period period = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate());
long days = period.getDays();

long hours = elapsed.getHour();
long minutes = elapsed.getMinute();
long seconds = elapsed.getSecond();
long milliseconds = elapsed.getNano() / 1000;

StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
msg.append(seconds);
msg.append("s ");
msg.append(milliseconds);
msg.append("ms");
if(minutes > 0) {
    msg.insert(0, "m:");
    msg.insert(0, minutes);
}
if(hours > 0) {
    msg.insert(0, "h:");
    msg.insert(0, hours);
}
if(days > 0) {
    msg.insert(0, days == 1 ? " day, " : " days, ");                
    msg.insert(0, days);
}

System.out.println(msg.toString());
```

Thanks for your time =)

Comment: I don't understand why elapsed won't be always equal to 1:1:3:4:5000? (D:H:M:S:ms)

Comment: I did something similar once, here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636583/convert-minutes-into-a-human-readable-format/19637037#19637037

Comment: @libik Thanks, your code is very helpful, I will bookmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need the `PeriodFormatter` from `JodaTime`. See below links:

[How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

[Formatting a Duration in Java 8 / jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827047/formatting-a-duration-in-java-8-jsr310)

Given these two, I suggest using `JodaTime` for `Duration`.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about JodaTime, but I don't want one more dependency in my project only to do this once in the whole code.
Anyway, the second link answers my question: there's no JodaTime's `PeriodType` equivalent in Java Time API.